If I have a container of water vapor at 110c and 1 Bar and suddenly raise the pressure to 2 bar, how "fast" does the water condense?
More basic form of question: If I have water vapor at a temperature and pressure at which it would remain  water vapor and I suddenly increase the surrounding pressure to a point which the temperature inside is below the boiling point of water how fast/rapid does the water vapor condense?
I do not necessarily mean: "how long does it take for ALL the WV to condense, but how long does it take for the h20 molecules to condense."
(I suppose that the WV condensing would also lower the containers pressure assume that the container will maintain static pressure the entire time despite WV volume decreasing.)(If temperature would change as well, assume that is also static.)

Well, cloud chambers work since the water vapor does not start condensing immediately.

I review the kinetics of nucleation here, starting around "Consider slight overheating past one of the transition points in the diagram above." For this problem, we'd replace "slight overheating" with "pressurization." The answer is very sensitive to the density and type of nucleation sites (e.g., dust particles, surface asperities in the container walls) in the chamber. If this gets at what you're asking about, we could discuss adapting the model to a driving force of pressure rather than temperature.

You are talking about adiabatic compression, which usually results in a sizeable temperature increase.  My guess is that no water would condense.

I once cleaned a teapot very carefully, filled it with water, and heated it.  And heated it.  It didn't boil.  I then added a tea bag.  The water flashed into steam, virtually nothing left in the teapot.
So, as vapor condenses it releases the heat of vaporization, warming the local environment, preventing condensation.  I suppose, like cloud seeding, it depends on nucleation sites.  I like the cloud chamber remark.  You could always trigger condensation with a cosmic ray.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
